# connect axi timer to microBlaze in vivado

Tags: vivado

I am working on vivado on a NoC that contain an arm processor (zynq) and three microBlaze processors and I am sending data from arm to a microBlaze and  I want to measure the time that the data take to be received at the microBlaze, I connected the arm to AXI timer and I found it in pripheral drivers in SDK but I do not know how to connect the microBlaze, any help?!